# Questions regarding default integer value

Tags: c

I noticed some differences when I make some minor changes on the following codes:

```
#include<stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
    int arrow;
    printf("%d\n", arrow);
    int wheel[12]={17, 38, 23, 17, 19, 41, 13, 17, 12, 11, 15, 23};
    int initialValue = wheel[arrow];
    printf("%d\n", initialValue);
    arrow = (arrow + 1) % 12;
    printf("%d\n", arrow);
 }
```

As I erased the final two rows the initial value of arrow is 1 which corresponds to the value '38' in the array. However, with the complete code the initial value of arrow turns to 0, which points to the value '17' in the array. I want to know why that is the case?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: **Undefined behavior**

Comment: [`arrow` has automatic storage duration, so its initial value is indeterminate](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p6).

Answer (score 2):

For objects defined inside a function without `static`, there is no default value. Their initial value is indeterminate, and, generally, the behavior of using one without setting the value is undefined.